# is there a way to highlight all the special accent characters in sublime text or any other text editor?

Tags: encoding, sublimetext2, html-encode, htmlspecialchars

I a using the the HTML encode special characters in Sublime text to convert all the special character into their HTML code. I have a lot of accented characters in different parts of the file. So, it would be great if I could select all the special character and then use the plugin to convert all at once!

Is there a regex that helps select all special characters only?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Yes.

Sublime text supports regular expression and you can select all non-ASCII (code point > 128) characters. This regex find should be enough for you:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]
```

Just search and replace.

But if you are doing manual HTML encode in the first place you are doing it wrong. Save your files as UTF-8 encoding (Sublime Text 2 default) and make sure your web server also sends out those files as UTF-8. No conversion, encoding or anything needed.

Comment: However, when coding an HTML email, using UTF-8 usually isn't an option because it's not supported in all email clients. In these cases, manual HTML encoding is necessary.

Comment: @mtnorthrop: Can you please tell when UTF-8 causes issues? Namely I am sending out tons of HTML emails and I'd like to know which kind of problems I can run into.

Comment: can't thank you enough for this...have been trying to look at a non utf-8 data file for hours trying to figure this out

Comment: Great! This regex solution is not limited to sublime editor, it also works for any other editor that supports regex search

Answer (score 15):

#### Just as further reference (or as complement):

The Sublime Text 2/3 package, named [`Highlighter`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Highlighter), can (as his name says) highlight some characters with regex...

> *"You can also add a custom regex for characters to highlight."*

So, with this package, plus `@Mikko Ohtamaa` answer, we can edit the file...

`highlighter.sublime-settings -` **`User`**

...and include the proposed regex, (expresed here as **`[^\\x00-\\x7F]`**) to end up with something like this:

```
{  
    "highlighter_regex": "(\t+ +)|( +\t+)|[^\\x00-\\x7F]|[\u2026\u2018\u2019\u201c\u201d\u2013\u2014]|[\t ]+$"  
}
```

The result would be an **automatic highlight** of any *"non-ASCII (code point > 128) characters"* in our file.

Note, this wil not made a selection of those characters, only will highlight them to easily realize if you have any.

Answer (score 7):

### Another plugin option

I recently wrote a plugin dedicated to highlighting non-ascii characters:
https://github.com/TuureKaunisto/highlight-dodgy-chars

The exactly same functionality can be achieved with Highlighter but with the less generic Highlight Dodgy Chars plugin you don't need to write a regular expression, you can just list the non-ascii characters you don't wish to highlight in the settings. The European special characters are whitelisted by default.