# Rails - invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, character-encoding, compatibility

I'm losing all my hair on this:

My rails server starts ok, but whichever the request to it is made (except assets and public content), I get this error :

```
ArgumentError in HomeController#index

invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
```

with this framework trace (no application trace)

```
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/stack_frame.rb:19:in `from_exception'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/error_page.rb:52:in `backtrace_frames'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:114:in `log_exception'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:87:in `rescue in protected_app_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (0.9.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/augustin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/augustin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/augustin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

My team works on windows and it works fine on their platform, but the bug occurs on my computer in ubuntu. Everything worked fine until now, if I rollback to my latest commit it works again, so the error is in the merge.

Questions are:

- How can I debug this issue since it's not really verbose?
- What does the error actually means? That Ascii is expected and that's not what we have OR that ascii is found and that's not what's expected?
- Is the error more likely to be in a gem, in the application controller?
- Is there a way to filter all special characters to have an idea where it comes from?
- What other info would be usefull to help me debug this?

Readings:

- [When run bundle get invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095845/when-run-bundle-get-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii) : both solutions offered didn't work for me
- [is there a way to highlight all the special accent characters in sublime text or any other text editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976022/is-there-a-way-to-highlight-all-the-special-accent-characters-in-sublime-text-or) : many results, but nothing especially weird

Attached:

`Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

# Database
gem 'pg'

# Database Init
gem 'seed_dump'
# gem "seedbank"

# gem 'active_model_serializers'

# HAML
gem 'haml', '4.0.3'
gem 'html2haml'

# Front-end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', :git => 'git://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.git', :branch => '3'
# gem 'font-awesome-sass-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'jquery-tokeninput-rails' # tag and autocomplete for conversation

# Shared mustache templates for rails 3.
gem 'smt_rails'

# Attachements
gem 'paperclip', '3.4.2'

# Share on Social Network
gem 'social-share-button'

# Jquery Upload File
# gem "jquery.fileupload-rails"
# Map
gem 'mapbox-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/aug-riedinger/mapbox-rails.git'
gem 'leaflet-markercluster-rails'

# Authentication
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1', :require => 'bcrypt'
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', "1.4.0"
gem 'oauth2'
gem 'fb_graph'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.5.0'    
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
end

platforms :ruby do
  group :development, :test do
    gem 'railroady'
  end
  group :production do
    gem 'aws-sdk'
    gem 'unicorn'
    gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  end
end

# Messaging - Notifications
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'mailboxer'
gem 'pusher'

gem 'amistad'

# Pdf generation
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawnto'

# Payments
gem 'activemerchant'

# SEO
gem 'dynamic_sitemaps'
gem 'metamagic'

# Static files
gem 'markdown-rails'
```

Thanks for helping a desesperate guy ...

Comment: http://www.railshorde.com/blog/invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I finally found the solution by checking out every commit in the history (`git log`), testing, and finally making a `git diff <commit_hash> <previous_commit_hash>` to see what changed.

I had non-ASCII char in a helper (loaded on every call apparently):

```
  def group_currency(group)
    currency = group.currency
    case currency 
    when 'EUR'
      haml_tag "€"
    when 'USD'  
      haml_tag "$"
    when 'GBP'
      haml_tag "£"   
    end

  end
```

So adding this at the beggining of the file solves it:

```
#encoding: utf-8
module GroupsHelper
...
```

But what I find more questionning is why can't Rails locate and report in the log the file that rises the problem...
I created an issue on Rails for this: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12041

Comment: I'll just add what I learned from your github issue. To find out **what file** causes the problem run rails in production: `rails server -e production` and you will get precise error message.

Comment: Sure, or running test environment does the job also!

Comment: If you're not sure what the offending characters are, try running this command:
`$ grep --color='auto' -P -n "[\x80-\xFF]" /*`