# How to search a unicode character using its code point in sublime text

Tags: regex, unicode, sublimetext

From what I understand, unicode characters have various representations.

e.g., code point or hex byte (these two representations are not always the same if UTF-8 encoding is used).

If I want to search for a visible unicode character (e.g., `汉`) I can just copy it and search. This works even if I do not know its underlying unicode representation. But for other characters which may not be easily visible, such as [zeros width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), that way does not work well. For these characters, we may want to search it using its code point.

### My question

If I have known a character's code point, how do I search it in **sublime text**  using regular expression?  I highlight **sublime text** because different editors may use different format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unicode character whose [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) is `CODE_POINT` (code point must be in hexadecimal format), we can safely use regular expression of the format `\x{CODE_POINT}` to search it.

### General rules

For unicode characters whose code points can fit in two hex digits, it is fine to use `\x` without curly braces, but for those characters whose code points are more than two hex digits, you have to use `\x` followed by curly braces.

### Some examples

For example, in order to find character `A`, you can use either `\x{41}` or `\x41` to search it.

As another example, in order to find `我`(according to [here](https://codepoints.net/U+6211), its code point is `U+6211`), you **have to** use `\x{6211}` to search it instead of `\x6211` (see image below). If you use `\x6211`, you will not find the character `我`.

[image]

Comment: I could successfully search `a0` without curly braces.

Comment: I mean it is `better` to use curly braces not `must`. If you separate these two situations, you may forget to use curly braces when dealing with unicode chars which have more than 2 byte code point.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think it have fully answered my question, i.e., `how to search a unicode character using its code point`. More feedback is welcomed. Actually I answered my own question because editing to your answer is rejected. I hope the downvote is not this reason.

Answer (score 9):

1. Zero width space characters can be found via:

`\x{200b}`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KpyNXh/1)

2. Non breaking space characters can be found via:

`\xa0`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ft3GR9/1)

Comment: I have seen people using `\x` followed by code point of some characters without curly braces, e.g.,  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995175/6064933). But for some characters, the curly braces seem important: without curly braces, we can not find them.  What is the rule behind this?

Comment: If the hex representation of the code can fit in 2 letters max, curly braces are optional, else they are required.